# How to remove automated chart titles generated by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I generated a boxplot using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

country = ['A' for z in range(1,6)] + [ 'B' for z in range(1,6)]
sales = [random.random() for z in range(1,11)]
data =pd.DataFrame({'country':country, 'sales':sales})

bp=data.boxplot(by='country')
```

[image]

Pandas generated automated titles of the chart.
 1. 'Boxplot grouped by country'
 2. 'sales'

I can get rid of 1 using:

```
bp.get_figure().suptitle('')
```

But I cannot figure out how to get rid of the second 'sales'

I am struggling with it searching through stack overflow for the whole day and nothing seems to work.

I am using Python 3.6.1 together with Conda. The code I run in Jupiter notebook.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: `set_ylabel('')`?

Comment: dosn't changing anything for me. It should be proceed by anything? f.e. `bp.get_figure().gca().set_ylabel("")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You also need to get rid of the title on the axes via:

`bp.get_figure().gca().set_title("")`

and if you want to get rid of the [country] part too:

`bp.get_figure().gca().set_xlabel("")`