# remove main title from histogram in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I want to remove "SalesPrice" from the plot.
and remove the borders (keep the x,y axes and remove the top border)
and I want to convert the numbers to be written with (e).
I will be grateful for any help.

```
salesHist = ames.hist(column='SalePrice', grid = False, edgecolor = 
"black", color = 'khaki')

for ax in salesHist.flatten():
   ax.set_xlabel('home sale price')
   ax.set_ylabel('Density')
```

[image]

Comment: "ames" is the name of the dataset

Comment: Three questions, three duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373386/8881141  https://stackoverflow.com/q/925024/8881141 https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371674/8881141